# Product ID or name is not searchable

Tags: content-search, sitecore-commerce, azure-search

I am working on Sitecore commerce 9 update-1. 
Many customizations are already done till now.

For searching I'm using the default Search component.

Issue :-
Product is not searchable by Product ID/Name.

Please share your thoughts where I can check - why Product items are not coming in search results.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what version of solr do you have? is it solr cloud?

Comment: locally I have solr 6.6.2 and in production it's azure search.

Comment: first check the Index configuration file for crawling root path. The path should include catalog items as well.

Answer (score 1):

OOTB Sitecore Commerce is searching from product id.

When you search inside Commerce->Merchanding the products are search on **Catalog_Item_Scope** index.

Please have a look on the  solr index 
https://solr:8983/solr/#/catalog_items_scope/query . On your solution the name of the index probably is different.

If you search for *:* you will see results:

[image]

If you don't see any results in Catalog_scope_index can you try to run postman script to reindex all catalog items:

[image]

Comment: I have issue in website search functionality. Sample URL { 
 'https://sxa.storefront.com/search?q=7042127' }. Here, by default search is done from **web_index**. And search result for Catalog Name/Id is coming nil for me.